# what is the difference between $("#context .searched") and $(".searched",$("#context"))?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had that question in mind for a long time.

Theoretically, jQuery core function accepts an optional value that can be a DOM element  - `$(".searched",$("#context")[0])` - or a jQuery object - `$(".searched",$("#context") )` .
I discovered that last question reading that fine [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1876-Your-jQuery-Selector-Context-Can-Be-A-jQuery-Object.htm).

But i really cant see the difference between use a context and pass a more complex css expression. If there is no difference in the way it works, is there any perfomance difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference would be that `$(".searched", context);` can take a variable as a context as well.  It is effectively doing `$(context).find('.searched');` under the hood, and I think the second version is more readable anyway, so I usually use that.

The use for this situation would be something like this:

```
$.fn.highlightSearch = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    $('.searched', this).addClass('highlighted');
    // the commented line performs the same thing:
    // $(this).find('.searched').addClass('highlighted');
  });
};

$('#context').highlightSearch();
$('.somethingElse').highlightSearch();
```

Notice that in this case, you can't simply append the new selector on the end of the original.

If you have no other reason to hold a copy of `$('#context')`, then using `$('#context .searched')` is going to be quicker, and simpler.  However, if you already had `$('#context')` stored in a variable, its better to use `.find(select)` or the `$(selector, context)` form to search for your contained elements.

Comment: This solves my question totally. I'll use the context only if i have to store it for another purpose. I find more natural the $('#context').find('.searched') too, so maybe, i will not use the context syntax anymore.

Answer (score 3):

It gets converted to a DOM element (in Sizzle, the context portion) to search in either of your cases, [ultimately doing](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L148) a [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) under the covers.

If you're concerned about performance (why *not* be as fast as possible?), you should use this instead:

```
$("#context .searched")
```

This version [gets converted back into a jQuery object](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L153):

```
$("#context")[0]
```

So it's a bit slower on the jquery side, since it has to be wrapped in a jquery object *before* the `.find()` call, that performance difference is very minimal, but it's the only difference so I'm noting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Readability: a CSS selector like `$("#context .searched")` is far more readable than the other.